# pip installing packages failed

Tags: python, docker, pip, pycharm

With PyCharm I tried to add a project interpreter for my Docker container

[image]

but then I get this incomprehensible error.

```
Invalid requirement: 'redis\>=2.10.5'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 82, in __init__
    req = Requirement(req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 96, in __init__
    requirement_string[e.loc:e.loc + 8]))
InvalidRequirement: Invalid requirement, parse error at "'\\>=2.10.'
```

[image]

What can I do about it?

Comment: Have you tried updating pip and setuptools? `pip install -U pip setuptools`

Comment: @NelsonYeung In the Docker container or in my host os? I don't understand.

Comment: Yes I tried updating inside the docker container. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation of `pip`:

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#examples

```
$ pip install SomePackage            # latest version
$ pip install SomePackage==1.0.4     # specific version
$ pip install 'SomePackage>=1.0.4'     # minimum version
```

It seems you have to use apostrophes for a minimum version.

Comment: but I use a `requirements.txt` and I see that apostrophes are used when it crashes and bugs out.

Comment: In the error message it seems like the executed command is missing the apostrophes.

Comment: The requirement contains a backslash as to be seen in the console output. Maybe that is the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Backslash in `redis\>=2.10.5` is the culprit of the problem. Replace `redis\>=2.10.5` with `'redis>=2.10.5'`.